# How to downcast AnyObject to pid_t

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I'm trying to get pid_t of a specific window (using CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo). After fighting with type casting in swift I finally can get the windowOwnerPID

```
var windowOwnerPIDRef = CFDictionaryGetValue(windowInfoRef, unsafeAddressOf(kCGWindowOwnerPID))
var windowOwnerPID = unsafeBitCast(windowOwnerPIDRef, AnyObject.self)
```

Now i need to cast the variable windowOwnerPID from AnyObject to pid_t to to feed into function

```
var appRef: AXUIElement = AXUIElementCreateApplication(testPid).takeRetainedValue()
```

but don't know how to do it. Anyone has experiences with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Constants/Constants.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCGWindowOwnerPID), the value for the `kCGWindowOwnerPID` key is a `CFNumberRef` type (encoded as `kCFNumberIntType`) that contains the process ID of the application that owns the window.

Using the toll-free bridging between CoreFoundation and Foundation types
and between Foundation and Swift types, the following should work:

```
let wlist = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(
                CGWindowListOption(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly), 0).takeRetainedValue()
for wdict in wlist as [ [ String : AnyObject] ] {
    if let pid = wdict[kCGWindowOwnerPID] as? Int {
        println(pid)
        // pid is an Int here. If necessary, convert to pid_t with
        let pidd = pid_t(pid)
    }
}
```

(so that calling `unsafeAddressOf()` and `unsafeBitCast()` is not even necessary).

With Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta) an explicit conversion from
`CFStringRef` to `String` is required (thanks to Rob Napier for the
feedback):

```
let wlist = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(
    CGWindowListOption(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly), 0).takeRetainedValue()
for wdict in wlist as! [ [ String : AnyObject] ] {
    if let pid = wdict[String(kCGWindowOwnerPID)] as? Int {
        println(pid)
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you can skip all the way to `as? pid_t` and skip the `NSNumber` step. Swift will unbox the number for you. Also in my experiments (at least in the beta), I needed to use `String(kCGWindowOwnerPID)` as the key. I don't believe that `CFString` will bridge to `String` automatically like `NSString` does.

Comment: @RobNapier: Automatic unboxing works with Int, but not with fixed-size types like pid_t aka Int32. Thanks for the feedback and suggestions, answer updated accordingly.

Comment: @RobNapier: `if let pid = wdict[String(kCGWindowOwnerPID)] as? pid_t` compiles in Swift 1.2, but never gives true.

Comment: You're right; I had it working with NSNumber, and confused it with my test with `pid_t`, but retesting, it doesn't pass.

Comment: @RobNapier: In case you are interested: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/265260.